# $1$-norm on $\mathbb R^p\times\mathbb R^p\times\dots\times \mathbb R^p$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

$1$-norm on $\underbrace{\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^p\times\dots\times \mathbb R^p}_{n \text{ copies}}=\mathbb R^{np}$

now suppose I write $x,y\in\mathbb R^{np}: x=(x_1,\dots, x_n): x_i\in \mathbb R^p, y=(y_1,\dots, y_n): y_i\in\mathbb R^p$
as a row vector say.

then is the following inequality holds?

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\|x_i-y_i\|_1\le \|x-y\|_1$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\|x\|_1=\|x_1\|_1+\cdots+\|x_p\|_1$? Because in that case, your inequality is trivially an _equality_.

Comment: @Arthur, all I know about the definition of $1$ norm/metric is as follows: If $ p=(p_1,\dots,p_n), q=(q_1,\dots,q_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ then $\|p-q\|_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|p_i-q_i|$ :(

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the norm $||.||_1$ You have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x_i-y_i||_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{p}|(x_i)_j-(y_i)_j|=||x-y||_1$$
viewing $x$ and $y$ as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{(np)}$